# Php GET notice problem

Tags: php, get, notice

Calling "index.php?pConta=1&pDataInicial=01-01-2000&pDataFinal=31-12-2000" I get this notices:

```
[08-Oct-2009 17:30:35] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pConta in index.php on line 1
[08-Oct-2009 17:30:35] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pDataInicial in index.php on line 2
[08-Oct-2009 17:30:35] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pDataFinal in index.php on line 3
```

index.php source:

```
<?php
    $conta = $_GET['pConta'];
    $dtIni = $_GET['pDataInicial'];
    $dtFin = $_GET['pDataFinal'];
?>
```

And the "var_dump($_GET)" shows me following:

```
array(3) { ["pConta"]=> string(1) "1" ["pDataInicial"]=> string(10) "01-01-2000" ["pDataFinal"]=> string(10) "31-12-2000" }
```

And $conta, $dtIni and $dtFin have excepted values.

Comment: What PHP version are you using? What OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem! I'm using xajax (an ajax php library) and it was calling the url without params.

Comment: Sorted :) Was getting a bit confused as to why that wouldn't unless there was something like that we wernt aware of :) Don't forget to mark it answered :)